# How to run create-react-app projectname on non root drive?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am using npm 6.12.0, lubuntu 19.04, and create-react-app 3.2.0. When I run create-react-app project name in non-root drive,

`error "npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded"`

came up, but when i run in root drive it run properly. because of the limit in my root capacity storage, i should run in in non-root drive (SD Card as an external drive), so how could I do to run it in non-root drive?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this force cleaning cache will solve

```sh
npm cache clean --force
```

if above does not solve ,then try to remove node module

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -r node_modules
npm install
```